# (type: T.Type) makes generic method work whereas without it T cannot be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, types

I'm using a simple method to run a fetch request on my Core Data DB. I'm housing most of my code within one protocol that will have default implementations that certain things will extend. My code is as follows:

```
protocol Modelable {
    func testFetch<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T]?
}

extension Modelable {
    func testFetch<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T]? {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data"),
            result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    
        return result as? [T]
    }
}
```

Then I simply call it on a struct that conforms to `Modelable`

```
let modelableExtended = ModelableExtended()
print(modelableExtended.testFetch(type: SomeType.self)) // Prints
```

What's weird about this code is that if I remove the `type: T.Type` from the method definition and where I call it, I'll get the following error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

How exactly does passing a type into this method make it so it works? Isn't that just a parameter on the method itself, passing or not shouldn't change anything.

Comment: If you don't tell Swift what `T` is, what type of array should `result` be casted to, in `result as? [T]`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're saying but what I'm saying is that if I leave out the parameter for testFetch() of `type: T.Type` it throws the `could not be inferred` error whereas if I include that property, it casts to the type I pass in. I don't understand how that parameter dictates the type of `T`

Comment: Right, `SomeType.self` is of type `SomeType.Type`. You are passing a `SomeType.Type` to a method that needs a `T.Type`, so `T` is now bounded by `SomeType`. There are no other information, or other type parameters, so we are done. `T` is inferred to be its only bound - `SomeType`. Do you want even more implementation details than this?

Comment: And .... if you do not have this parameter, then T isn’t bound (and you get the error).  I posted an answer that shows how you can try to bind the return type instead `[T]?`

Comment: @Sweeper If you could go deep into how it works, I would very much appreciate that. I've been trying to wrap my head around Generics and this has me very confused on what exactly Swift is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: You just need to explicitly set the resulting type. I would make your method throw and return a non optional.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/TypeChecker.md) has all the details you need. IMO, if you are just trying to "wrap your head around generics", then I suggest you not to go too deep into the implementation. "Here's a method that can accept any `T.Type`. You gave it a `SomeType.Type`. Ah, `T` is `SomeType`!" Don't worry about how the compiler does it, as long as that makes sense to you on a natural language level, you understand type inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to pass in the type, you can do something like this instead

```
let modelableExtended = ModelableExtended()
let result: [SomeType]? = modelableExtended.testFetch()
print(result)
```

At some point you have to say what `T` is by either passing in some parameter that refers to it or by assigning the result.

Generics are a compile-time feature. Perhaps you are thinking that they are like `Any` or `AnyObject` where you never have to say the type and then you can find out at runtime what you actually have.  This isn’t how generics work.

A generic let’s you write code that can work with a lot of different types, but the code that actually runs is using a specific type that was inferred from its context. If it cannot be inferred, then the code will not compile and never be run.

Comment: So by referring to `T.Type` Swift handles that in the background to determine what the actual type is?

Comment: It’s happening a compilation time. When you use a generic — you are saying — At some point — when I actually use this, I will tell you what T really is.  You usually do this by providing a parameter that matches the pattern so that T can be figured out. But, you can also do it by assigning the return value to a variable with a known type.

Comment: @JoeScotto Swift is a type inferred language. you can say `let result: [SomeType] = modelableExtended.testFetch()` or `let result = modelableExtended.testFetch() as [SomeType]` I prefer to explicitly set the type

Comment: @LeoDabus But how is that done behind the scenes? What I'm confused about is how exactly does Swift know to infer that specific parameter as the type for `T`.

Comment: You are explicitly setting the resulting type. Same as way as `let double: Double = 2`

Comment: It’s using the code around the call to match the type